# Seem some themes in usr/share/themes on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: edubuntu

So many themes are in usr/share/themes .but in appearance only three default themes are there how I can apply from usr/share/themes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see more theme options with [Gnome-Tweak-Tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool).

Comment: Will you send me .deb of GNOME tweak tool

Comment: Since Edubuntu uses Unity desktop the Unity Tweak Tool might be more appropiate, @user73898 you can find both in Software Center.